# Mouselistener not working with if statement

Tags: java

I have one last error in a 2d program game in which the player clicks on a randomly appearing object(essentially whack a mole) and then shows how many times the player caught the creature.

Everything works except when trying to increment the player's score when the target is pressed. If I turn off the if statement, the MouseListener increments by +1 every time I press the mouse. It appears that the error is in my 'if' statement. I had an original suggestion by the compiler when using '.equals' that said the statement is unlikely, so I investigated the data types and changed the if statement to use '==' instead of '.equals'.

```
package activity1;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class CreaturePanel extends JPanel {

Random CreatureGenerator = new Random();

private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1000;
private final int WINDOW_LENGTH = 1000;
private Point point = null;
private int creaturecounter;
private final int creatureSize = 20;
private int creatureXPosition = 500;
private int creatureYPosition = 500;
private JLabel CreatureLabel;
private JTextField CreatureText;
private Timer timer;

public CreaturePanel () {               
CreatureLabel = new JLabel("Number of times Creature Caught: ");
CreatureText = new JTextField(10);
add(CreatureLabel);
add(CreatureText);          
addMouseListener(new CreatureMouseListener());          
timer = new Timer(5000, new CreatureListener());            
this.setFocusable(true);            
timer.start();
}       

public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
{
  super.paintComponent(page);
  page.setColor(Color.red);
  page.fillOval(getCreatureXPosition(), getCreatureYPosition(), creatureSize, creatureSize);
  }  

package activity1;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CatchTheCreature {    

public static void main(String[] args) {
   JFrame frame = new JFrame("Catch the Creature!");
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);            
   frame.setSize(1000, 1000);

   CreaturePanel PanelFinal = new CreaturePanel();
   frame.getContentPane().add(PanelFinal);              
   frame.pack();
   frame.setVisible(true);          
  }    
}

public int getCreatureYPosition() {
    return creatureYPosition;
}    

public void setCreatureYPosition(int creatureYPosition) {
    this.creatureYPosition = creatureYPosition;
}    

public int getCreatureXPosition() {
    return creatureXPosition;
}    

public void setCreatureXPosition(int creatureXPosition) {
    this.creatureXPosition = creatureXPosition;
}

private class CreatureMouseListener implements MouseListener {

   public void mousePressed (MouseEvent event)
    {       
        if(getCreatureXPosition() == event.getX() && getCreatureYPosition() == event.getY())
        {
            creaturecounter+=1;
            CreatureText.setText(Integer.toString(creaturecounter));
            repaint();
            }
        }        

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {}   
}
private class CreatureListener implements ActionListener
{                   
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
  setCreatureXPosition(CreatureGenerator.nextInt(WINDOW_WIDTH));
  setCreatureYPosition(CreatureGenerator.nextInt(WINDOW_LENGTH));    
  repaint();
  }
```

}
}

Any suggestions to help point me in the right direction. Apologies in advance for sloppy code. Thanks.

Comment: so the point they have to click on is exactly 1 pixel in size? sounds difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking the exact position of the creature - the top left corner.

```
    if (getCreatureXPosition() == event.getX() &&
        getCreatureYPosition() == event.getY())
```

So the user will have to click on the exact pixel of the top left corner of the creature. Try something like this which accounts for the creatures size in pixels..

```
    if (event.getX() >= getCreatureXPosition() &&
         event.getX() < getCreatureXPosition() + creatureSize &&
         event.getY() >= getCreatureYPosition() &&
         event.getY() < getCreatureYPosition() + creatureSize)
```

This will give you a simple box to click within. You could also try to detect where you have clicked on actual pixels of the creature rather then the background.

Comment: I had a hunch about the pixel size, I should have tried that. Thanks mate!